# How can I get full entry from a column from on 10 characters given when the actual entry contains 20 characters and the field is in varchar?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The given value is like this

```
4213076600
```

and I need to fetch this `89013106904213076600` from the table using select

I know I can get it by using like function but the given values are around 100

The query I'm using is

```
select left(name, 50)
from production.product
where left(name, 50) in ('ring', 'heel')
order by productid;
```

Please change it accordingly

Comment: Is your CAPS LOCK stuck? Furthermore, your question lacks: 1) Information 2) Respect for the people answering here

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: `SELECT "SORRY, I'M TYPING SQL HERE"` (somebody actually tried to pull that on me the other day)

Comment: don't shout, anyway it can't be heard.

Comment: Please dont use CAPS LOCK Faizan. It is the sign of anger. Dont you Know?

Comment: There is no need to shout. Please edit your question. Using all uppercase letters is considered rude and attention-grabbing.

Comment: @Kuya John: Has it ever occurred to you, as a user with 45k rep, that you could change more of this post than just formatting the code block?

Answer (score 2):

Simply change what you actually select: Use `SELECT NAME` instead of `SELECT LEFT(NAME, 50)`:

```
SELECT NAME
FROM Production.Product
WHERE LEFT(Name, 4) IN ('ring','heel')
ORDER BY ProductID;
```

Comment: it is showing empty column in result

Comment: That's because this will only work if all values in the `IN` clause are of the same length specified in the `LEFT` function. In the sample statement, you need to use `LEFT(NAME, 4)` instead of `LEFT(NAME, 50)`. However, please note that this will stop working correctly as soon as there are strings with a different length in the `IN` clause - their rows will never be returned.

Comment: but what if i have a less information but have to get a full numbers like in the question i have mentioned

Comment: @faizan: I have no idea what you are asking now. `SELECT NAME` will return the full column content.

Comment: thanks for your effort but i have got the answer